# Why is $ \sum_{n=0}^{k}|m-n|=\sum_{n=0}^{m}(m-n)+\sum_{n=m}^{k}(n-m)$?

Tags: analysis, summation, absolute-value

The problem is:

> Why is $$ \sum_{n=0}^{k}|m-n|=\sum_{n=0}^{m}(m-n)+\sum_{n=m}^{k}(n-m)\;?$$

Answer (score 4):

Note that $|m-n|=m-n$ for $n< m$ and $|m-n|=n-m$ for $n\ge m$.The given sum can thus be split as
$$ \sum_{n=0}^k|m-n|=\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}|m-n|+\sum_{n=m}^{k}|m-n|=\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}(m-n)+\sum_{n=m}^{k}(n-m).$$
The only remaining difference is that the summand for $n=m$ is missing from the first sum. But since $|m-m|=0$, this doesn't matter.

Implicitly, we used $0\le m\le k$ in the above. But the result also holds for $m>k$ or $m<0$, provided one interpretes sums with lower index greater than upper index accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Try to understand what it means.

The absolute value $| m - n |$ is $m - n$ when $n \le m$ and $n - m$ when $n \ge m$

Comment: You can get $\le$ and $\ge$ with `\le` and `\ge`, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align} \sum_{n=0}^{k}|m-n|&= \sum_{n=0, n \le m}^{k}|m-n| + \sum_{n=0, n \ge m}^{k}|m-n| \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{m}|m-n| + \sum_{n= m }^{k}|m-n|\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{m}(m-n) + \sum_{n= m}^{k}(n-m) 
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Recall that
$$
|u| =
\begin{cases}
-u,  & \text{if $u \leq 0$} \\
u, & \text{if $u \geq 0$}
\end{cases}
$$ thus
$$
|m-n| =
\begin{cases}
n-m,  & \text{if $m \leq n$} \\
m-n, & \text{if $m \geq n$.}
\end{cases}
$$